# Reshaping cells: transform a 1xj cell with i observations into a 1xi cell with j observations

Tags: matlab, cell, reshape

I want to know the best practice to reshape cells.

Let's say I have a 1x5 cell that has 2 observations in each cell. In my example, I will this cell VAR. In order to run an example:

```
cbar=linspace(0,1,2);
for i=1:5
    for j=1:2
VAR{i}(j)=i+cbar(j);
    end
end
```

Let's say I want to create another cell that will be 1x2 and will have 5 observation in each cell -so I am reshaping the VAR cell above. The way I am approaching this, which is not working, is the following

```
for i=1:5
    for j=1:2
   VAR_new{j}(i)=VAR{i}(j);
    end
end
```

It happens that for some reason the VAR_new is empty.

How can I do this properly? Thank you!

Comment: Why not just use a 3D array (or even a 2D one will do in this case)? It's more efficient, and you can do the operation you want with [`permute`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) (or even just transposition)

Comment: For this example indeed, it could be. I can give it a try. But in any case, I am still wondering why what I am doing is not working. Any ideas, @LuisMendo?

Comment: Can you try `mat2cell(reshape([VAR{:}],5,[]),5,repelem(1,10))` ?

Comment: You need to change `for i=5` into `for i=1:5`, and same for the other loop :-)

Comment: @UnbearableLightness, unfortunately, it doesn't work.

Comment: @LuisMendo: thank you :). Corrected. In fact, I will add an easier example to follow.

Comment: What do you mean with "it doesn't work" ? The result is a cell array, 1x10 with 5 observations in each cell

Comment: @UnbearableLightness, because the cells are filled with the wrong observations. I've have edited my example to be an easier example of 1x10 cells with 2 observations in each. The example is now such that the `VAR_new=mat2cell(reshape([VAR{:}],5,[]),5,repelem(2))' should result in a vector that would have the integers from 1 to 5, which is not the case. You can run yourself and check. In the new example it is easier to see your reshape is not delivering the correct output. But I appreciate and thank you!

Comment: How is the result not correct? For example, `VAR{3}(2)` is indeed the same as `VAR_new{2}(3)`

Comment: @LuisMendo, ah, yes. My bad. Ok that solves the issue!

Comment: @UnbearableLightness: would you like to add as an answer, please? Thank you! PS: still curious to know why my simple loop doesn't work... any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine [reshape](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) to reshape the matrix to the desired dimensions, and [mat2cell](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html) to convert the matrix to a cell array:

```
VAR_new = mat2cell(reshape([VAR{:}],5,[]),5,repelem(1,2));

>> VAR_new

VAR_new =

  1×2 cell array

    {5×1 double}    {5×1 double}

>> VAR_new{1}

     1
     2
     2
     3
     3

>> VAR_new{2}

     4
     4
     5
     5
     6
```

Comment: +1 for an elegant answer and teaching me about [repelem](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repelem.html)

Comment: Happy to help Laura. @b3 Cheers. repelem is redundant in this case however I left it as the original question asked for a 1x10 cell array.